# How to create web mapping web application with Map and rendering with million points or vector?

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, openlayers, mapbox, geoserver

I have to develop an **web based application**  Where I have **models**(car, truck) having
its Longitude and Latitude or vector points(models) of **1 million**.If i want to create web app, which my **users will be able to see their models over the map**, And even may be able to **edit it from client** (browser) side.Which tools or **Architecture** will i implement to render more than million vectors on map.As i am new to web mapping, I want to know how shall i create an interactive map, where user must be  able to retrieve  **old** ,**present** vector data of any format (stored in Data base) .And render it and show with map.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster

Comment: https://blog.mapbox.com/clustering-millions-of-points-on-a-map-with-supercluster-272046ec5c97

Answer (score 1):

You may want to think about how to generalize your display of information here for your users. I've blogged about an approach for [visualization of tens of millions of latitude, longitude pairs using Leaflet and Apache Solr](https://www.jack-reed.com/2015/06/29/visualizing-10-million-geonames-with-leaflet-solr-heatmap-facets.html). Solr's facet heatmap feature offers high performance generalization of geospatial data for visualization and query.

Comment: Actually Client must be able to move the marker from one place to another

Comment: And How will I save or update the altered markers or polygon area drown on over the map and which all tool will i need to use. From front end to back end.Can you guide me.So the i can dig more inside.